# matlabs latex directive produces a form leading to error by latex interpreter

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I stumpled upon the following issue:

I [turned a symbolic expression to his latex form](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html) like the following:

```
>> latex(sym(@(x)airy(x)))

ans =

    '\text{airy}\left(0,x\right)'
```

This is an example of a builtin function with no latex equivalent (unlike sin, cos, ...). Trying to use this expression in a legend using `legend({'$\text{airy}...$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex')`, I get the following error:

```
 Character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:
$f(x) = \text{airy}\left(0,x\right)$
```

This is caused by `text` being provided by `amsmath` package which is not loaded by the interpreter somehow. So I can fix this by replacing the text directive with `textrm`:

```
replace(latex(sym(f)), '\text{airy}', '\textrm{airy}')
```

But this shouldn't be needed. I expect a string produced by the latex directive in matlab to be processible by the latex interpreter coming with (or linked to) matlab.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this, e.g. on how to load the `amsmath` package? Yes, this is maybe possible, but very hard, so I'm not searching for a solution to hacky load it somehow. There [seems](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232055-is-there-a-hook-that-will-allow-me-to-change-the-document-style-and-or-add-packages-to-the-latex-fil#answer_187995) to be the possibility to add some own stylesheet while publishing, but I couldn't find anything related for legends or figure manipulation, this would be a better approach. You have any ideas on this?

Comment: Edited the question, now more clear that I don't want to do hacky things :)

Comment: It might not've been designed for further processing in MATLAB, rather for convenience in copying equations into a TeX editor. You can use `replace` also to change only the `\text` command to `\textrm`, or simply remove it all together to render it as text anyway.

Comment: Yeah, changed that in my code, that's more general and fixes the problem (at first, until there are other not standard directives put out by `latex`). But maybe somebody else is aware of that stylesheet thing or a way to say `latex` to only output basic directives. Still looking forward seeing some other helpful answers :)

Comment: For now your replacing approach seems best, but generally it appears to be a valid feature request or bug report.